# var char date not selecting in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

in my select query i have where condition on date and, i have that field in var char format. problem is query not working with year. my query is.

```
SELECT * FROM `timesheet_entry` WHERE `day_date` between '01/15/2017' and '01/28/2017'
```

when i run this query in phpmyadmin i am getting this.

[image]

it's selecting month and date right but it's selecting year with 2016 also. help me to solve this.

Comment: Better to use DATE type to storing date

Comment: Set day_date filed type 'date' and try again make sure the db date format and existing field format must be same

Comment: You should use a `DATE` DataType not a `VARCHAR` and then use the right dateformat like `0000-00-00` then the SQL should work

Comment: what is the datatype of `day_date`?

Comment: The best way to play with date field is store the date in epoc format i.e in integer format and you can fetch the data very easily in given date range

Comment: then how can i change my varchar field to date type without losing data. i tried but my all record set to 0000-00-00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If your datatype is varchar than use `STR_TO_DATE()` function.**

**your query should be:-**

```
 SELECT * FROM timesheet_entry
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(day_time, '%m/%d/%Y')
 BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/15/2017', '%m/%d/%Y')
 AND STR_TO_DATE('01/28/2017', '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Comment: Here you can't predict that day_time is always in format of  `'%m/%d/%Y'` as this field is varchar.
So i think this solution won't work with 100% efficiency.

Comment: If i had insert `'13/12/2016'` in day_time field of  specific data then your query wont be working.

Comment: how can i change my varchar field to date type without losing data. i tried but my all record set to 0000-00-00.